# Find the Name of Objects referenced in IQueryable and IEnumerable in ENtity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4

I am creating a generic function that have the function definition as:

```
  public static List<T> Func_IEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> q, ObjectContext dc, string CacheId)
```

**and one function as**

```
  public static List<T> Func_IQueryable<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, ObjectContext dc, string CacheId)
```

The question is that I want to find out the tables name,procedure name,function name and/or view name referenced in the Ienumerable or IQueryable Query

Is it possible with the Linq framework

And if not then we may convert the IEnumerable into **System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery** and finally using **ToTraceString** to get the pure SQL.

Now from Pure Sql can we get the object names.

Whether Sql Server has some functions to do the same if not, then how should I parse it to get desired results.

Thanks,

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like two parts would be involved here: Traversing the query to find all referenced entities, and extracting the info from the corresponding entities.  Both don't sound like easy problems.  Could you not just look at the mapping/"model", or use SQL Server profiling?

Comment: Why do you want to get the table names/function names?

Comment: @ Merlyn Morgan-Graham I want to implment the SqlCacheDepenedency in ASP.NET (Notification Service). I will pass the query to be cached, then in this function i will make SqlCacheDependencies of all referenced objects. Now for SqlCacheDepenedency we need a SqlCommand. Now SqlCommand i can create using pure sql or Object Query to totracestring

Comment: @Eranga I want to implment the SqlCacheDepenedency in ASP.NET (Notification Service). I will pass the query to be cached, then in this function i will make SqlCacheDependencies of all referenced objects. Now for SqlCacheDepenedency we need a SqlCommand. Now SqlCommand i can create using pure sql or Object Query to totracestring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `SqlCacheDependency` (featrue heavily dependent on SQL) why are you using EF (feature which tries to hide SQL as much as possible) in the first place? You are combining two features which were not designed to work together - that happens quite often in .NET framework.

`IQueryable` can be converted to `ObjectQuery` only if the object is `ObjectQuery` = it was created as query on exposed `ObejctSet` and you have never called `ToList`, `AsEnumerable` or other executing method on it. This also means that calling to stored procedure cannot be converted to `ObjectQuery`.

Real `IEnumerable` (executed query) cannot be converted to `ObjectQuery` and you cannot get any information about source of the result set from `IEnumerable`. This is case for all queries where `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` was called and for example for all calls to mapped stored procedures.